# Confusing result for panda qcut function

Tags: python, pandas

When reading the documentation for `pd.qcut?`, I simply couldn't understand its writing, particularly with its examples, one of them is below

```
>>> pd.qcut(range(5), 4)
... # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
[(-0.001, 1.0], (-0.001, 1.0], (1.0, 2.0], (2.0, 3.0], (3.0, 4.0]]
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 1.0] < (1.0, 2.0] ...
```

Why did it return 5 elements in the list (although the code specifying 4 buckets) and the 2 first elements are the same (-0.001, 1.0)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 0 is in (-0.001, 1], so is 1.

```
range(5) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The corresponding category of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is [(-0.001, 1.0], (-0.001, 1.0], (1.0, 2.0], (2.0, 3.0], (3.0, 4.0]].

Comment: Thanks, @quinlong! I failed to notice the half open range ( ].

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `range`

```
list(range(5))
Out[116]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

it is return 5 number , when you do `qcut` , `0`,`1` are considered into one range

---

```
pd.qcut(range(5), 4)
Out[115]: 
[(-0.001, 1.0], (-0.001, 1.0], (1.0, 2.0], (2.0, 3.0], (3.0, 4.0]]
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 1.0] < (1.0, 2.0] < (2.0, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]
```

Comment: sorry, I can't see any clearer with your explanation. Shouldn't the range of ```range(5)``` be [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]? Why were there two ranges of (-0.001, 1.0) in the example of help documentation?

Comment: @Jason cause one of the range need to cover both 0 and 1 , (0,1) will not include 0

Comment: Ah, I think I can follow now. However, why did it use bin (-0.001, 1.0) instead of (0.0, 1.0)?